# pandas select rows based on two column values

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I need the same name values ​​from different years. And if a name value only exists in one year, I need to subtract it.

```
d = {

    'Name':['A','B','B','C','D','D',

            'E','E','E','F','G','G'],

    'Year':[2010,2010,2012,2010,2011,2011,2010,2010,2012,2014,2015,2016]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['Name','Year'])

df
```

```
    Name    Year
0   A   2010
1   B   2010
2   B   2012
3   C   2010
4   D   2011
5   D   2011
6   E   2010
7   E   2010
8   E   2012
9   F   2014
10  G   2015
11  G   2016
```

expected df should looks like

```
Name    Year
1   B   2010
2   B   2012
7   E   2010
8   E   2012
10  G   2015
11  G   2016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df = df[df['Name'].isin(df['Name'].value_counts()[df['Name'].value_counts()>=2].index)]
```

Comment: It gives non-repeating values ​​in the name column but I need the same name values ​​from different years

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please let me know it worked or not @Robbods

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.duplicated` with `keep=False` argument to watch all the duplicates in your dataframe:

```
  df[df.duplicated(['Name'], keep=False)]
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution? Please, feedback.

Comment: Hour solution gives only unique  values ​​in the name column but I need the same name values ​​from different years

Comment: Please, kindly feedback to me.